# Why do std string and vector's destructor generate unnecessary code?

Tags: c++

I discovered that calling the destructors `~vector` and `~string` resulted in a much more than just deallocating any allocated heap in use. For vector it zeroed out the object as well which put it in the same state as simply declaring an empty vector, ie: `std::vector<int> v;` For strings, it deallocated any heap used but it also changed the string to match an empty string. That is, the same as `std::string s;`

There's nothing illegal about that. Arguably it makes the thing safe in case the programmer fails to replace the destructed object since the destructor will be called again at scope exit.

But I don't see any reason why it generates extra code to modify this memory that has no remaining use at all.

Why is this superfluous code generated?

**EDIT**
Turns out neither GCC nor CLANG change the object at all, they just destroy the allocated heap used by vector. So this excess code is only in MSVC.

[Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/ffTMbccbv)

**EDIT**
I found the area in std::string that is changing the string object. It's called _Tidy_deallocate() at location 4630 in xstring. No comments as to what's going on but the name is a hint and the key changes that apply to a short string are at line 4647-4650. Superfluous but it's clear the code changes the object to that of a `std::string{}`

```
// MSVC c++20, 32bit
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::cout, std::vector, std::string;

template<typename T>
void printobj(const T& x)
{
    const int N = sizeof(void*);
    // hack to show contents at the objects location. Not portable and probably UB
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(T) / N; i++)
        cout << (void*)((char*)&x + N * i) << " " << (void*)*(size_t*)((char*)&x + N * i) << "\n";
    cout << (void*) x.data() << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> v{ 1,2,3,4,5 };
    printobj(v);
    v.~vector<int>();  // deletes allocated space and changes v's guts to 4 null pointers. Same as empty vec.
    printobj(v);
    string s{ "123412341234" }; // short string, no heap used
    printobj(s);
    s.~string();    // changes to zero length string with s[0]=='\0'
    printobj(s);

    // prevent double dtor
    std::construct_at(&s, string{});
    std::construct_at(&v, vector<int>{});
}

    /* Output
    00AFFB30 00CFBDA8
    00AFFB34 00CF6DB8
    00AFFB38 00CF6DCC
    00AFFB3C 00CF6DCC
    00CF6DB8
    00AFFB30 00000000
    00AFFB34 00000000
    00AFFB38 00000000
    00AFFB3C 00000000
    00000000
    00AFFB0C 00CFBBB0
    00AFFB10 34333231
    00AFFB14 34333231
    00AFFB18 34333231
    00AFFB1C CCCCCC00
    00AFFB20 0000000C
    00AFFB24 0000000F
    00AFFB10
    00AFFB0C 00000000
    00AFFB10 34333200
    00AFFB14 34333231
    00AFFB18 34333231
    00AFFB1C CCCCCC00
    00AFFB20 00000000
    00AFFB24 0000000F
    00AFFB10
    */
```

Comment: What compiler, and what compiler switches? Debug mode will often do stuff like this, it would be more unusual for optimized code to waste time on it. Of course, it would be amusing if this only happens because you try to read the memory. Might want to examine assembly without actually telling the code to print it.

Comment: These destructors should be found in your compiler's header files. Did you try to look there to see what the destructors are doing, and perhaps there might be some helpful comments there?

Comment: @ShadowRanger MSVC 2022. c++20. Same in debug and release except the sizeof(v) is 12 bytes in release mode and 16 bytes in debug mode.

Comment: Sometimes the answer to questions like this is "just because".  Some coding guidelines advocate zeroing out (in some other cases scrubbing by overwriting with other data) dynamically allocated memory before releasing it, and others advocate setting a pointer to null after `delete`ing it.  A fair few developers follow such guidelines blindly/religiously (e.g. it is not actually necessary to set a pointer to null in a destructor since the pointer itself will no longer exist when the destructor completes, but people do it anyway).

Comment: @Peter I'd expect the library coders to have clear guidelines. I did also notice that the destroyed objects were not only left in a legal state, but the same state they are left in after a `std::move`  While no reason to do that it has the advantage of making the code the same and keeps things safe in case the programmer failed to do a placement new re-construction. I was just surprised to see it.

Comment: @doug  Library coders are human, and just as capable of following guidelines blindly as anyone else, no matter how clear the guidelines are.  And, BTW, `std::move()` does not actually affect state of an object - it allows code which calls `std::move()` to do things to the object.

Comment: @Peter But in this case it's clear what they did was intentional. That is reset the containers to their default values when empty containers are instantiated. Since libraries are run on massive user code bases this may well have been intentional because fewer faults would occur if the programs called the dtor twice in error.

Comment: So you're able to look at what code does, and know what was in the minds of developers?   There are plenty of real-world cases of programmers achieving something they didn't intend, or doing something because "the guideline said so" even if the guideline is unnecessary/inapplicable in their use case.

Comment: Is this legal? `std::string s("foo"), t("bar"); s.~string(); s = t;` It looks oh so wrong but with the string being reset to empty it would work.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow after the destructor call to `s` there is no `s` object for the assignment ie `s = t` is assigning `t` an object that no longer exists .  I agree it will probably work but I think it's technically UB.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Yeah. Clearly UB but it looks like MSVC allows it by patching the no longer alive string which makes no sense otherwise. OTOH, CLANG and GCC doesn't in the sense that if the string wasn't SSO, those would leave a dangling ptr. Neither of these change the no longer alive object's contents.